# How do I create a Category view from my CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, treeview

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails and I have a cron job that grabs a Category list CSV from my supplier. Once I have the list I add the columns to my database which in this case is MongoDB.

I want to reproduce the structure in a readable and navigable format. I have seen details about Mongo Tree, etc. but I'm not sure if this way to go.

**Model**

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :category_id, :type => Integer
  field :category_name
  field :category_description
  field :category_parent, :type => Integer

end
```

**Cron Task**

```
def categories
  categoriesHash = HTTParty.get('http://feed.suuplier.com/user=xxxx&format=csv')
  categoriesCSV = categoriesHash.parsed_response

  categoriesCSV.each_with_index do |item, i|
    if i != 0
      Category.find_or_create_by(category_id: item[0]) do |category|
        category.category_id = item[0]
        category.category_name = item[1]
        category.category_parent= item[2]
        category.save 
      end
    end
  end
```

**CSV**

```
Category ID        Category Name           Category Parent Id
4                  Electronics             0
5                  Audio Equipment         4
6                  Home Entertainment      4
7                  Photography             4
8                  Portable Audio          4
9                  Televisions             4
10                 Amplifiers & Receivers  5
11                 Audio Systems           5
12                 Cassette Decks          5
13                 CD Players              5
14                 Radios                  5
15                 HiFi Speakers           5
17                 MiniDisc Separates      5
18                 Tuners                  5
19                 DJ Equipment            5
```

The result needs to be:

```
Electronics
--- Audio Equipment
------ Amplifiers & Receivers
------ Audio Systems
------ Cassette Decks
------ CD Players
------ Radios
------ HiFi Speakers
------ MiniDisc Separates
------ Tuners
------ DJ Equipment
--- Home Entertainment
--- Photography
--- Portable Audio
--- Televisions
```

I could simply loop through but I didn't know if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: FYI, the MongoDB manual lists some common patterns & caveats for [Modelling Tree Structures](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/). Efficiency will depend on how you actually need to use the categories in your application. If you only have ~20 categories which are provided by an external supplier, you could even consider storing the tree in a single document. Will you be adding more information to the category data, or will this be replaced on every refresh from the supplier CSV?

Comment: Thanks Stennie - I will be replacing it every refresh.